# Attempting to change inkcanvas pen size using slider C# XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, slider

I have a slider with values 1-10. and an inkCanvas with default height and width of 1px. I am attempting to change the height and width based on the value of the slider. This is what I have tried but it gave me this error: "**Object reference not set to an instance of an object**". 
What does this error mean?

[image]

edit: included xaml code:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you must have code inside `penSizeSlider_ValueChanged` to change the `penSizes.SelectedValue`.
 So you need either to just remove `Value="1"` part from `<Slider..../>` in your XAML code and set the value in code behind, as that will trigger the `penSizeSlider_ValueChanged` event before you have chance to initialize your `penSize` comboBox (as you only set `Items` of `penSize` in `Window_Loaded` event).  Or you can initialize `penSize.Items` in XAML instead of in the code behind. and try again.

So you need to:

1. remove `Value="1"` part from `<Slider..../>` in your XAML
2. change `Window_Loaded` to:

   ```
   private void Window_Loaded (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
                for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
                {
                    penSizes.Items.Add(i);
                }

                penSizes.SelectedIndex = 0;
                //set slider's value here
                penSizeSlider.Value=1;
                //...rest code
   }
   ```

PS: It would be better to just set a breakpoint and debug by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that somewhere in your code, you're working with an object that still hasn't been initialized. Try to debug to find out which one.

Comment: I don't understand The code snippet above contains the majority of the code I'm using. It doesn't seem to have an issue with me setting the default values for the height and width on `Window_Loaded`.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with that part of your code, I would like though to see your complete xaml and code behind, just to debug it myself. 

What you have provide gives me no errors, and seems to work fine.. Changing the slider, changes the pen size. You must have something else that is cause the error to show.

Comment: Thank you, I included the xaml to my question.